# How to start dead executor in Jenkins using Groovy script?

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I have installed jenkins 1.6 on ubuntu 12.0. I have one executor running in my jenkins. But this executor is dying randomly for some jobs. How can I start an executor if it is dead ? IS there any groovy script?

LOGS:

> Sample log of dead job :
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   /home/jenkins/jobs/shared.fileio.release_1.0/builds/4 already existed;
>   will not overwite with shared.fileio.release_1.0 #4
>           at hudson.model.RunMap.put(RunMap.java:189)
>           at jenkins.model.lazy.LazyBuildMixIn.newBuild(LazyBuildMixIn.java:178)
>           at hudson.model.AbstractProject.newBuild(AbstractProject.java:1011)
>           at hudson.model.AbstractProject.createExecutable(AbstractProject.java:1210)
>           at hudson.model.AbstractProject.createExecutable(AbstractProject.java:144)
>           at hudson.model.Executor$1.call(Executor.java:328)
>           at hudson.model.Executor$1.call(Executor.java:310)
>           at hudson.model.Queue._withLock(Queue.java:1251)
>           at hudson.model.Queue.withLock(Queue.java:1189)
>           at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:310)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the ownership of the Job and restart the slave service.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this? We could use more detail.